# Updating "live" WPF Canvas (Polyline), when change in PointCollection happends

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, mvvm

I'm creating a Polyline in a WPF canvas that is suppose to update it's position, when hitting on a button, based on calculations that happends in my model. I'm using a MVVM pattern.

My XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="10" Command="{Binding Path=RunAnalysisCmd}">Rune analysis!</Button>
        <Canvas>
            <Polyline Points="{Binding ModelPathPoints, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In my ViewModel I have a PointCollection property where the path points are stored.

```
private PointCollection _modelPathPoints = new PointCollection();
public PointCollection ModelPathPoints 
{ 
    get { return _modelPathPoints; }
    set
    {
        _modelPathPoints = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ModelPathPoints");
    }
}


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

The method RunAnalysis works fin, and I have tested it using Consol output. My problems are that the canvas is not changing when the points in the PointCollection are changing.

```
public void RunAnalysis()
{
    double angle = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i=i+10)
    {
        Model.TranslateModelEdgeNodes(i, i);
        Model.RotateModelEdgeNodes(angle);
        angle = angle + 0.1;
        AddModelPointsToPointCollection();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

public void AddModelPointsToPointCollection()
{
    //ModelPathPoints.Clear();
    PointCollection modelPathPoints = new PointCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModelEdgeNodes.Count(); i++)
    {
        modelPathPoints.Add(new Point( XXX, XXX )) // Not important what XXX, XXX is
    }
    modelPathPoints.Add(new Point(XXX, XXX )); // Not important what XXX, XXX is
    ModelPathPoints = modelPathPoints;
}
```

Does anyone see the problem??

Comment: Sorry.. That was just a type error by me here on stack overflow. It is {Binding ModelPathPoints, ...}. in my code

Comment: Just in case you are running RunAnalysis in the UI thread: `Thread.Sleep(500)` will then block the UI thread. You may use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead.

Comment: I don't think thats the problem. If I just removes the Thread.Sleep, everything are the same..

Comment: And can you still interact with the window, i.e. is it redrawn when you move or resize it? Clemens' comment is right: If you call `RunAnalysis()` on the UI thread, WPF will get no chance to redraw the window because the UI thread is blocked all the time. Therefore, you will have to call the method on another thread, e.g. using a `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid wondering whether Thread.Sleep is interfering with the UI doing it's thing, why don't you use a click-event, that will make it do one iteration that should be visibly apparent?

Within that property-setting, you could then verify that it is being assigned with each click, verify the values of the points being assigned, and that the PropertyChanged event is happening.

Oh - and I assume your view-model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and that you're assigning an actual value to your PropertyChanged event somewhere that you're not showing in your code above?

Let me know if that helps - if not, I'll create a project and check this for you. Best.